# Fourier transform vanishes on a half line

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $\phi \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\phi>0$. Prove that there is an $F$ with $|F|=\phi$ and the Fourier transform $\widehat{F}(x)$ vanishes on $x<0$ if and only if the following inequality
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\log \phi(x) dx}{1+x^2}>-\infty
\end{equation} holds. My though is that the function
\begin{equation}
   u(z)=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{y}{(x-t)^2+y^2} \log \phi(t) d t
\end{equation} is harmonic in the upper half plane and consider $f=e^{u+iv}$, where $v$ is its harmonic conjugate. Since $f$ is analytic in the upper half plane, Fatou theorem for the upper half plane implies that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{y \to 0} |f(x+iy)|=\phi(x)
\end{equation} holds a.e. on the real axis. However, I can go further and I don't know how to apply the given inequality in my qustion. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why does $u$ exist (in other words why is the integral defining it convergent)? The fact that $\phi$ integrable ensures it cannot be plus infinity, but why cannot the lintegral be $-\infty$? Maybe it has to do something with the other hypothesis on $\log \phi$ after all?

Comment: What Conrad is saying is that $\phi \in L^1$ implies $\|\max(\log \phi,0)\|_{L^1} = \| 1_{|\phi|>1}\log(\phi) \|_{L^1}\le \| 1_{|\phi|>1}\phi \|_{L^1}<\infty$ so $\|\frac{\max(\log \phi,0)}{1+x^2}\|_{L^1}<\infty$ together with 

$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\log \phi(x) dx}{1+x^2}>-\infty
$ it implies $ \frac{|\log \phi(x)| }{1+x^2}\in L^1$.

Comment: Thank Conrad and reuns, I think I have got the points.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different version of this is proved in Paley and Wieners book.

For yours, for the one direction let
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        &f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \hat f(t)e^{itx}\,dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat f(t)e^{itx}\,dt \quad (x\in\mathbb{R})\\
        &\phi(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \hat f(t) e^{itz}\,dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat f(t) e^{itz}\,dt \quad(z\in\Pi^+)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
It is easy to show that $\phi\in H(\Pi^+)$ (upper half plane) and $\lim_{y\to0} \phi(z) = f(x)$ a.e.

Hence let $g(\alpha) = \phi(z)$ and $h(e^{it}) = f(x)$ where $x = i\frac{1+ e^{it}}{1-e^{it}} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ z = i\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}$.
It is clear that $g \in H(\Pi^+)$. One can also show that $h \in L^2(T)$ (unit circle). One can then compute a poisson integral and have that $P[h] = g(re^{it})$.

By Jensen's Theorem (this takes a bit of manipulation) one can then show that
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\log|g(re^{it})|| \,dt
        &\le \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|h(e^{it})|^2\,dt - \log \left| \frac{g(\alpha)}{\alpha^k} \right|_{\alpha=0} - k \log r
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Since $\lim_{r\to 1} \log|g(re^{it})| = \log|f(x)| = \log|h(e^{it})|$ a.e. taking the limit as $r\to1$
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\log|h(e^{it})|| \,dt &< \infty
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Hence
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\log\varphi(x)| \frac{\,dx}{1+x^2} &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\log|f(x)|| \frac{\,dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |\log|h(e^{it})|| \,dt < \infty
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
And the result follows.

For the other direction, by Holder's inequality one can show that
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\log\varphi(x)| \frac{\,dx}{1+x^2} < \infty
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Then by Fatou's Theorem for the upper half plane, $u$ is a real harmonic function in $\Pi^+$ and
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    \lim_{y \to 0} u(z) = \lim_{y \to 0} u(x+iy) = \log\varphi(x) \quad \text{a.e.} \ (\mathbb{R})
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Consider $g(z)=\exp(u(z)+iv(z))$ where $v$ is the harmonic conjugate of $u$ on the upper half plane. Then one can show via Jensen's and Holder's Inequalities that
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        |g(x+iy)|^2 &= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{y|\varphi(t)|^2}{(x-t)^2+y^2}\,dt \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Hence by Fubini one can show that
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \sup_{0<y<\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |g(x+iy)|^2\,dx < \infty 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Hence by one of the Paley-Wiener Theorems there exists $G\in L^2(-\infty,\infty)$ that vanishes on $(-\infty,0)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
    g(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(t) e^{itz}\,dt \quad (z\in\Pi^+) 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
One can show that $\lim_{y\to 0 } g(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} G(t) e^{itx}\,dt = \hat G(-x)$ a.e. on $\mathbb{R}$.
Hence let $f(x) = \hat G(-x)$. Hence almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$ one has
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        |f(x)| = \lim_{y\to 0} |g(z)| = \lim_{y\to 0} \exp(u(z)) = \varphi(x)
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
By Plancherel one has in $L^2(-\infty, \infty)$ that
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        &G(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat G(x) e^{itx}\,dx \quad (t \in \mathbb{R}) \\
        &\implies \hat f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat G(-x) e^{-itx}\,dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat G(x) e^{itx}\,dx = G(t) 
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Hence $\hat f(t)$ vanishes on the half line $(-\infty, 0)$.